# Cannot downgrade ICloud subscription: which reason?

Tags: icloud

A friend of mine has a 200Gb. ICloud subscription, of which she is using 130 Gb. She wants to downgrade it to the free option, but when she tries to follows the steps in https://support.apple.com/en-al/HT207594#ios on her iPhone, she can't: the corresponding option to "Change storage plan" doesn't work (you click on it and nothing happens). I can think of two possible reasons:

1. She has too much storage, and iCloud won't let her downgrade until she deletes all the excess data in her iCloud Drive.
2. She unknowingly paid for an annual subscription and it hasn't run out yet. She let me enter her iCloud account to have a look, but I haven't been able to find any place that lists her subscription status.

Which is it?

Comment: Did you see this article ? https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201058

Comment: @ankii: doesn't really make much difference, does it? It says that we need to get into ICloud's settings and click on "Manage storage"... but when we do that, nothing happens. It doesn't let us go further than that either way.

Comment: "When you downgrade your iCloud storage plan, the storage decrease takes effect after your current monthly or annual subscription ends."

Comment: @ankii: well, yeah, but the thing is that it won't even let us downgrade. We click on "Manage storage" and nothing happens.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250509915 "You should have to delete content to get down to the 5 gig before you can downgrade, so you can choose what to remove." https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7548931 Could you use some other device to free up storage ?